# Подвисает цикл while в скрипте при выполнении условий - не могу понять причину

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок с календарем, где внутри тега

`<div class="dopbsp-month-year">April 2019</div>`

выводится месяц  и год (подтягивается с объекта Date) начиная с текущего.
Кнопка с классом `.dopbsp-next-btn` сдвигает календарь на месяц вперед (May 2019, June 2019), все стандартно.

Я хочу настроить чекбокс **id** `autumn-check` таким образом, чтобы сдвиг был на осенний месяц. 
Условие **if** выполняется, но **while** почему-то подвисает, в консоли выводится зацикленный текущий месяц, а кнопка `.dopbsp-next-btn` не работает.

В чем проблема и как исправить?

**Код:**

```js
$("#autumn-check").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var month = $(".dopbsp-month-year").text().split(' ')[0];
    if (month !== "September" || month !== "October" || month !== "November") {
      while (month !== "September" || month !== "October" || month !== "November") {
        $(".dopbsp-next-btn").click();
        month = $(".dopbsp-month-year").text().split(' ')[0];
        console.log(month); // April
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Not Autumn");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="autumn-check" name="autumn"><label for="autumn">Autumn</label></p>
<div class="container">
<div class="dopbsp-month-year">April 2019</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dopbsp-next-btn"><span class="dopbsp-info">Next month</span></a>
</div>
```

Обработчик `$(".dopbsp-next-btn").click();`

```
function() {
  methods_calendar.init(methods_calendar.vars.startYear,
    methods_calendar.vars.currMonth + 1);
  $('.DOPBSPCalendar-navigation .dopbsp-previous-btn', Container).css('display', 'block');
}
```

**UPD** Пробую сделать через `setInterval()`, но после первой итерации сразу выходит

```
var checkAutumn = setInterval(function() {
  if (month !== "September" || month !== "October" || month !== "November") {
    $(".dopbsp-next-btn").click();
    month = $(".dopbsp-month-year").text().split(' ')[0];
    console.log(month);
    clearInterval(checkAutumn);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: @yar85 спасибо, понял! А каким образом тогда подойти к выполнению задачи?

Comment: @Вася обработчик `$(".dopbsp-next-btn").click();` приведите в вопросе.

Comment: @yar85 написал какой то дикий бред. Вы это сами придумали что ли?

Comment: @Максим Степанов привел, но это навряд ли чем-то поможет, обработчик берется из плагина и выполняет функционал по сдвигу календарного месяца с датами, событиями и прочим

Comment: @Вася не нужно каждый раз при клике календарь заново инициализировать

Comment: @Максим Степанов инициализировать что? Поясните

Comment: @Вася methods_calendar.init каждый раз при клике не надо. Там наверняка должен быть метод смены месяца.

Comment: @Максим Степанов это обработчик плагина календаря, он свои функции выполняет от и до как часы

Comment: @Вася в любом случае он инициализируется один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` выполняется синхронно - поэтому, если значение в условии выхода из цикла изменяется асинхронно, то нет шансов на то что это изменение данных произойдет: в таком случае, цикл будет крутиться бесконечно (или, до тех пор пока интерпретатор не прибьет скрипт).

Под спойлером пример асинхронного цикла с проверкой.

```js
$('#autumn-check-async').click(function () {
  console.clear(); 
  if (!this.checked) return; 
  const months = ['September', 'October', 'November'], 
        dateEl = $('.dopbsp-month-year').first(), 
        btnEls = $('.dopbsp-next-btn');
  const getMonth = () => dateEl.text().split(/\s+/)[0]; 
  let month = getMonth(); 
  if (months.includes(month)) {
    console.log('Autumn'); 
    return; 
  }
  console.log('Not Autumn...'); 
  btnEls.click(); 
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const nextMonth = getMonth(); 
    if (nextMonth === month) return; 
    if (months.includes(nextMonth)) {
      clearInterval(interval); 
      console.log('Autumn'); 
      return; 
    }
    month = nextMonth; 
    btnEls.click(); 
  }, 0); 
}); 

$('.dopbsp-next-btn').click(function (e) {
  const date = new Date($('.dopbsp-month-year').first().text()); 
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1); 
  $('.dopbsp-month-year').text(
    date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })
  ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="autumn-check-async">
  <label for="autumn-check-async">Autumn (async)</label>
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dopbsp-month-year">April 2019</div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dopbsp-next-btn">
    <span class="dopbsp-info">Next month</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

Но гораздо проще будет использовать общий обработчик события, и выполнять изменение данных **до** их вывода в DOM (то есть, сначала считаем, и только затем выводим).
Это хорошая практика не только в простейших случаях, как здесь с датой, а в общем и целом - ведь чем сложнее и больше становится скрипт/веб-приложение, тем значительнее задержки из-за "лишних" промежуточных обращений к DOM.
Короче, вот пример:

```js
$('#autumn-check, .dopbsp-next-btn').click(nextMonth);

function nextMonth(e) {
  const date = new Date($('.dopbsp-month-year').first().text());
  let month = incMonth(date);
  if (e.target.id === 'autumn-check') {
    while ((month < 8) || (month > 10))
      month = incMonth(date);
  }
  $('.dopbsp-month-year').text(
    date.toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })
  );
}

function incMonth(date) {
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  date.setMonth(month);
  return month;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="autumn-check" name="autumn">
  <label for="autumn-check">Autumn</label>
</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="dopbsp-month-year">April 2019</div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dopbsp-next-btn">
    <span class="dopbsp-info">Next month</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Во втором примере, проверка состояния чекбокса для демонстрации принципа не требуется (и думаю что с добавлением такой проверки, сложностей не возникнет).

Comment: попробуйте покликать Ваш чекбокс туда-сюда. это баг или фича? :)

Comment: @humster_spb, задумано как фича (см. текст под примером) - чисто для сокращения длины выражения `if` и кол-ва кликов при проверке. Но можно и как баг воспринимать))

Comment: @yar85 спасибо, но несколько не то. У вас `.dopbsp-next-btn` заменяет просто названия месяца, а я писал, что у него назначение гораздо больше - сдвигает календарь (с датами, определенными событиями) на месяц вперед просто целиком не стал приводить, поэтому для меня такой способ, к сожалению, не подойдет..

Comment: @Вася, К сожалению, я не джедай, поэтому сдвигать календари и другие предметы средствами JS еще не умею - как и читать мысли. Для примера инкремента значения в текстноде DOM через цикл (без зависания), вполне достаточно данного кода сдвига даты на месяц(ы) вперед.

Comment: @yar85 я пробовал сделать, как вы говорили сразу через `setInterval`, но после первой итерации выходит.. Код соответствующий привел в конце вопроса в первом посте

Comment: @Вася, я обновил ответ, добавил вариант с ожиданием переключения на каждой итерации.... код не сокращал, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: @yar85 вам лично минус за то, что у вас "обработчиков клика асинхронны" и одновременно чего то ждут. Не вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, ок, спасибо. Учи матчасть о цикле событий.

Answer (score 0):

А ни кто не заметил условия цикла, да?

```
while (month !== "September" || month !== "October" || month !== "November")
```

Ну, я тоже хорош.

```
while (month !== "September" && month !== "October" && month !== "November")
```

А это вообще убрать можно

```
if (month !== "September" || month !== "October" || month !== "November") {
```

Comment: не понял вас, поясните про условия цикла. Смотрю, но не понимаю зачем `&&` ?

Comment: А зачем || ? У вас всегда будет выполняться условие. Вам же надо выйти из цикла, когда выбран осенний месяц?

Comment: условие ведь не выполнится, если month будет равен `September`,`October` или `November`. А вот, если `April`, то да

Comment: Когда && не выполняется. Когда || выполняется.